# How to remove pagination when custom search is used in datatables

Tags: jquery, html, pagination, datatables

I want to apply the search filter based on only 2 columns.

For that I have created two text fields

```
<input type="text" id="type" name="type" placeholder="Filter by User Type"></td>
<input type="text" id="dept" name="dept" placeholder="Filter by Department"></td>
```

If I apply datatable on my table using

```
var table = $('#inbox').DataTable();
```

and apply this on my text-field

```
   $('#dept').keyup( function() {
        table.columns(2).search(this.value).draw();
    } );

    $('#type').keyup( function() {
        table
        .columns(0)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    } );
```

Then the custom search is working fine. But in this case pagination and default search are by default included, which is not required.

When I use

```
   var table = $('#inbox').dataTable({
        "bPaginate" : false,
        "bLengthChange" : true,
        "bFilter" : false,
        "bSort" : true,
        "bInfo" : true,
        "bAutoWidth" : true
    });
```

instead of

```
var table = $('#inbox').DataTable();
```

Then custom search is not working.

Any idea how to get custom search without pagination and default search provided by datatable?

Answer (score 0):

a quick idea...
try using this

```
var table = $('#inbox').DataTable({
        "bPaginate" : false,
        "bLengthChange" : true,
        "bFilter" : false,
        "bSort" : true,
        "bInfo" : true,
        "bAutoWidth" : true
    });
```

Capital DataTable instead of dataTable